# cannot create regular file 'filename': File exists

Tags: cp, concurrency

I've been getting this strange error message in one of my build scripts - `cp` fails, returning the error "File exists". I've even tried using `cp -f`, which should overwrite the file if it exists, but the error still shows up. Running `cp` to overwrite existing files works perfectly when I do it manually. What could cause this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a race condition. `cp` checks if the destination file already exists, and if not - overwrites it. The problem was happening because this `cp` command was being run twice in parallel, which caused the file in question to sometimes appear *after* checking whether it exists, but *before* the attempt to create the file. The `strace` output looks like this:

```
# Command was "cp a b"
stat("b", 0x7fff89510620)               = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("a", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("b", 0x7fff895103a0)               = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
# File b will be created at this point in time
open("a", O_RDONLY)                     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("b", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
```

Here's some bash code used to catch this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

touch a

f() {
  while true; do
    rm -f b
    strace -o /tmp/cp${BASHPID}.trace cp a b || break
  done
}

cleanup() {
  kill -9 %1 %2
}

f &
f &

trap cleanup exit

wait
```

This same error can occur with `mkdir -p` or any other action that attempts to overwrite a file. Using `flock` can help avoid race conditions in cases like this.

Comment: I ran into this exact same situation.  I chose to handle it via the `||` operator.  Sort of a poorman's try/catch.  I.e., `cp ... || echo "skip copying due to other thread"`.  Or something similar...

Comment: I hit this issue while running a single `cp`

Comment: Ran into the same problem. How did you debug it?

Comment: Got an strace on the failing `cp`.